# Remove grass texture

Tags: mesh

[image: mesh base]

Hi, can anyone tell me how to remove the grass from the mesh shown, it is linked by a texture file but I can't seem to get rid of it. Thanks Nicola

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a particles system on your object.

Go to the particle panel here. Near the green arrow you can click on the "eye" icon (just hides the particles) or click on the minus sign (to delete the particles).

At the bottom, the texture you are (probably) talking about :

[image]

If you remove it, you model may be "full of grass".

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, it turned out to be vertices, I was able to select them and delete them all. Now I just have to figure out why it exports to wrl without the texture files. Other files export fine from the same .blend file but not this one.